# run python script once a month, pass parameters to script

Tags: python, date, cron, cron-task

Hi to everybody and thanks in advance for the help.

I have a python script which is started via command line with a string like this one:

```
python example.py [start-date] [end-date] [fixed-param]
```

I would like to make it automatically run once a month (on ubuntu), but every month the [start-date] and [end-date] have to be different.
The script downloads some data about the previous month, so if it runs, say, the 1st of may, it have to pass `[start-date]='01-04-2017'` adn `[end-date]='30-04-2017'`.

in my intentions the script would run every month without my intervention so i would need to set the dates as variables or something.

What would be the easiest solution to this?

Comment: I think you could use `datetime` to 'discover' the previous month. You would just get the current date and subtract one month. Could that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using Crontab to automate the python script running. For info on how to get started with Crontab, look here:

[Crontab how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Check out these two previous stack overflow questions for info on how to pass parameters and set a date variable in crontab:

[passing parameters to a python script with crontab](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26595/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-a-python-script-run-from-crontab%22passing%20parameters%20to%20a%20python%20script%20with%20crontab%22)

[date variables in crontab](https://serverfault.com/questions/339814/how-do-you-set-a-date-variable-to-use-in-a-log-for-crontab-output)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you get the date in the Python script. Below is an example of how to figure out the previous month.

```
import datetime

def last_month(today=None):
    if today is None:
        today = datetime.date.today()
    lastmonthend = today.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    lastmonthstart = lastmonthend.replace(day=1)
    return lastmonthstart, lastmonthend

print(last_month())
```

Running this on April 18, 2017 gave me:

```
(datetime.date(2017, 3, 1), datetime.date(2017, 3, 31))
```

Which you could use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format to:

```
('01-03-2017', '31-03-2017')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had more experience with crontab and Python than I would like and here are some lessons I have learned:

1. capture all of your output (stdout/stderr) in your script
2. capture any output that 'leaks' out of your script in your crontab line (be careful to append or to overwrite, depending on your needs)
3. test your script using an empty environment, such as with `env -i` - cron runs  with a special environment.  If you don't test with a bare environment, you will often discover that you had unfulfilled dependencies on your non-bare environment
4. build your arguments into your script
5. if you are unfamiliar with #2 and/or #4, wrap your python script with a sh/bash script
6. beware '%', escape carefully - it's special!

Here are examples:

```
0   0   1   *   *    /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py 2>&1 >> /tmp/leaked_cron_script_py.out
0   0   1   *   *    /path/to/my/script.bash 2>&1 >> /tmp/leaked_cron_script_bash.out
```

Here is an example of a script.bash including ugly date command examples, although I highly recommend using the .py approach and datetime as suggested by Tom:

```
first_day_of_last_month=$(date -d "last month" +01-%m-%Y)
last_day_of_last_month=$(date --date=@$(( $(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01)"  +%s) - 86400)) +%d-%m-%Y)
/path/to/my/script.py $first_day_of_last_month $last_day_of_last_month $FIXED_PARAMETER 2>&1 >> /tmp/leaked_cron_script_py.out
```

I would test this with `env -i /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py` or `env -i /path/to/my/script.bash`

Comment: Thank you, i have to research some of the topics you told me about but this was great help